# How to enable Windows UWP for flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, uwp

I followed https://medium.com/flutter-community/publishing-flutter-windows-apps-to-microsoft-partner-center-with-codemagic-b1962575510c but the channel dev and beta do not have the option to enable uwp:

```
Flutter 3.1.0-9.0.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f28e570c8c (5 weeks ago) • 2022-06-14 13:39:33 -0500
Engine • revision 74ee6b5afd
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-165.1.beta) • DevTools 2.14.0
PS C:\Users\lz> flutter config --enable-windows-uwp-desktop
Could not find an option named "enable-windows-uwp-desktop".


 Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

channel `dev` (which is deprecated) also gives the same error.

On stable it has the option:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1288], locale en-GB)

PS C:\Users\me> flutter config --enable-windows-uwp-desktop

Setting "enable-windows-uwp-desktop" value to "true".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.
```

However when I do `flutter create myapp`, it only has a windows folder (win32) not a winuwp like it should.

I'm on Windows 10, fresh Flutter and Visual Studio SDK installation with Windows 10 SDK C++ installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As UWP is being phased out by Microsoft, the Flutter team is focusing on the Win32 side instead to limit the scope. The support for UWP was removed entirely [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102172).

Check out the main issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14967#issuecomment-1085490495